# How can I modify the Quick Edit Module to have a better UX for end-users?

Tags: 8, navigation, entities

For a current project I'm working on we're trying to leverage the "In Place Editor" functionality provided by the [Quick Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickedit) module.

Our main goals are to:

1. Have a module that allows us to perform Create Update and Delete options in-line on only fields that needs the functionality.
2. Make it so that there is a single visible button which says "Edit" on some content that is always used to enter the "In Place Editing" mode.

Instead, the [Quick Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickedit) module provides us with:

1. Quickedit on any and all fields that are editable by the user.

   - This works really well for site and content adminstrators, but, our target audience is the end-user of the site.
2. A contextual link (a pencil icon by default) which you must first click. This link then shows a menu for options "Quick Edit", "Edit", "Delete" (and any others that have been placed by modules hooking into the Contextual module).

Clicking "Quick Edit" then simply enables the ability to edit in line. At which point, you still have to click on a field within the context in order to get the field to appear as an editable form input (and it's not immediately obvious that's an available option).

What is the best way to go about achieving a slightly more stream-lined, end-user oriented, in place editing system in drupal 8?

tl;dr

Drupal gives me this:

[image]

I'd like this instead:

[image]

Comment: why you blur the name of the user who submitted the info?

Comment: you need this in Drupal 8?

Comment: I honestly don't know. And yeah, Drupal 8.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? Or any information at all about customising quick edit?

Comment: I did not. The most likely answer is to create a custom plugin based off of the Quick Edit plugin (in core) that has the functionality.  It's a pretty bloated and time consuming approach that requires a heavy learning curve. I've since moved away from Drupal for reasons such as this.  Using raw jQuery, or something like React.js - this is a very simple task.

Comment: Over a year later, this question is still difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check https://www.drupal.org/project/simpler_quickedit to do exactly what you need